# How to move money to the default bitcoind wallet?

Tags: bitcoind

I am using bitcoind and have been playing around.

Recently I used the `sendtoaddress` command to send 0.50btc without realizing the implications of this command versus `sendfrom`.  Now when I list my accounts I see the following:

```
$ bitcoind listaccounts
{
    "" : -0.60010000,
    "w1" : 0.74584297,
    "w2" : 0.00022000,
    "w3" : 0.00000000
}
```

So at this point my main/default wallet has -0.60010000 and my w1 wallet shows 0.74584297.

I can list the default wallet address using:

```
$ bitcoind getaddressesbyaccount ""
```

However, is it possible to transfer funds locally to the default wallet or should I just use a explicit sendfrom with w2's address?

Is there a way to move 0.74584297 to the default wallet without having to send over the network and incur a fee?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, we have the bitcoind `move` command:

```
$ bitcoind move "w1" "" <amount>
```

These kinds of transactions do not incur a fee:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Accounts_explained#Account_-.3E_Account_Transfers

Comment: Ahh - I wasn't sure if the "" would toss my money into /dev/null or something.  Thanks!

Comment: This is gold. "would toss my money into /dev/null"